# NO_MATCHING_ABIS error when installing *some* Android apps in Anbox

Tags: android, libraries, adb, anbox, cpu-architecture

Since Anbox currently does not come packaged with an app store, the only way to install applications is through ADB as follows:

```
adb install /path/to/file.apk
```

I have been able to successfully install QuickPic and Snapseed this way, however when I try to install Opera Mini or WPS Office, I receive the following error:

```
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113]
```

I'm wondering whether this is an Anbox problem, Ubuntu problem, or ADB problem, and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take a look at the error message again:

```
Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113]
```

This means that the app in question uses native C/C++ libraries, but the APK doesn't include a version that library which has been compiled for the CPU architecture of the the target device. Unlike Java, C/C++ code is not cross-platform, nor is it cross-architecture.

Some apps have different APKs for the different CPU architectures.

But, bottom line, this is the app developer's fault, not yours.

Comment: So I should download apk's that support x86 architecture? And those will work?

Comment: @SumeetDeshmukh - An APK only needs to explicitly support x86 if it has native code. Most apps are written purely in Java and will just work.

Comment: Have the same problem even with Google Play

Comment: @Almaron you need the x86 version of the Play Store then